# Problems with MySql Database calls in C++ Classes

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I'm currently developing a desktop app that acesses a remote MySql database with Qt/C++. My approach was to create multiple .h/.cpp files (corresponding to different ui widgets) and call a general .h/.cpp database manager file that handles login, querys, etc. Unfortunately I am kinda stuck because either I get the "QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection '*databaseName*' is still in use, all queries will cease to work." or another kind of odd mistake like 'query.exec: database is not open'.

I've been searching for a day and I can't find anything that helps my case so I decided to try my luck here :)

i'll leave you the database manager and login .h/.cpp files atm:

**db.h**

```
#ifndef DB_H
#define DB_H

#include <QtSql>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QMessageBox>

class db
{
private:
    friend class login;
    QSqlDatabase dataBase;
public:
    db();
    ~db();
    bool login(QString, QString);
};

#endif // DB_H
```

**db.cpp**

```
#include "db.h"

db::db()
{
    dataBase = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", "*connection name*");
    dataBase.setHostName("*host*");
    dataBase.setPassword("*host-password*");
    dataBase.setDatabaseName("*connection name");

    if(!dataBase.open())
    {
        //error message
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Open...";
    }
}

db::~db()
{
    if (dataBase.isOpen())
    {
        dataBase.close();
    }
    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("*connection name*");
}
```

**login.h**

```
#ifndef LOGIN_H
#define LOGIN_H

#include "db.h"
#include <QDialog>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QSqlDatabase>

namespace Ui {
class login;
}

class login : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit login(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~login();

private slots:
    void on_login_button_clicked();

private:
    Ui::login *ui;
};

#endif // LOGIN_H
```

**login.cpp** -> where the problem is currently happening

```
#include "login.h"
#include "ui_login.h"

login::login(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::login)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

//Basic Configurations:

}

login::~login()
{
    delete ui;
}

void login::on_login_button_clicked()
{
    QString userID = ui->user_insert->text();
    QString userPassword = ui->pass_insert->text();

    qDebug() << userID << userPassword;

    //if conditions to check no one tampers with the limits in lineEdits

    else
    {
        QSqlDatabase loginCall = QSqlDatabase::database("*connection Name*");
        if (loginCall.isOpen())
        {
        qDebug() << "Also Open...";
        //call a db.hdb.cpp file to execute the login of the user
        }
    }
}
```

I think it's important to say that in the main.cpp I create an instance of the database.

Like I said, I've searched for quite a while and the current method I was trying was calling the current connection with

```
QSqlDatabase loginCall = QSqlDatabase::database("*connection Name*");
```

but from here on I can't acess the public funcions of db.h/db.cpp

Can anyone suggest a solution or say what I am doing wrong? If it's stupid bash me for it, it's deserved ahah but I'm quite tired of seeing videos and endless posts and not finding a fix.

Sorry for the long post, thanks in advance!

Comment: Qt is new to me, it is for sale, not for free. I see from your code, you can't call `db`'s functions because `loginCall` has nothing to do with `db` class. There should be an instance of `db` created somewhere for you to use with your login-user.

Comment: MYSQL --> change to `QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", "*connection name*");`

Comment: I have an instance created in main, to establish connection when the app opens. One fix I tried was to open an instance when needed so, in login, I create a db instance, call the login function and close it after. But I get a Qsqldatabase::removeDatavase warning/error message, hence why I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `"QSQLITE"` as the driver name when calling `QSqlDatabase::addDatabase` as you are trying to use MySQL you should be using `"QMYSQL"` instead.

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#addDatabase for a list of driver names.